# Why is "border-color" overridden by "color"?

Tags: css

I have the following css:

```
.isActiveFilter {
  color: black;
  background-color: rgba(0, 184, 170, .5);
  padding: 15px 10px 10px 10px;
  border-color: red;
  border: 3px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

For some reason, border color renders as black, not red as I would expected, as `border-color` is set after `color`. Thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why is “border-color” overridden by “color”? .... border color renders as black, not red as I would expect, as `border-color` is set after `color`. Thoughts?

Your problem lies within how you've declared your `border-` properties:

```
border-color: red;  /* sets the border color to red */
border: 3px solid;  /* sets the border color to default (black) */
```

You're using the shorthand for all border properties using `border`, and since you didn't specify any color within `border`, it's set to the default color, which is `black` in this case, [as defined by the `color` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border)<sup>1</sup>.  And since you're declaring `border` *after* `border-color`, you're over-riding `red` with `black`.

Simply remove `border-color` and specify any border color within the `border` property...

```
border-color: red;      /* <-- REMOVE THIS LINE */
border: 3px solid red;  /* set the border color here */
```

---

<sup>1</sup> [*"A `<color>` denoting the color of the border. If not set, its default value is the value of the element's `color` property (the text color, not the background color)."*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border)

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border) - "A <color> denoting the color of the border. If not set, its default value is the value of the element's **color** property (the text color, not the background color)."

Comment: @Pangloss, thank-you for clarification.  Updated answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

> The `border` CSS property is a shorthand property... `border-width`, `border-style`, and `border-color`... A `<color>` denoting the color of the border. If not set, its default value is the value of the element's `color` property (the text color, not the background color)... - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border)

The shorthanded `border: 3px solid;` (without a color), the color is then inherited from the `color` value of the element. Example 1:

```css
span {
  color: blue;
  border: 3px solid;
}
```

```html
<span>Text sample</span>
```

If `color` is undefined on the element, it will look for the `color` on the parent element, if it's also undefined on the parent, it will fallback to the browser default color which is `black`. Example 2:

```css
body {
  color: green;
}
span {
  border: 3px solid;
}
```

```html
<span>Text sample</span>
```

And the **order matters**, if you set it with the following order, It will work as expected. Example 3:

```css
span {
  border: 3px solid; /*first*/
  border-color: red; /*second*/
}
```

```html
<span>Text sample</span>
```

But, it would be easier to use a complete shorthanded set:

```
border: 3px solid red;
```

Answer (score 2):

You used the shorthand definition of border, but didn't specify the colour so it defaulted to black. You have 2 options:

```
border-color: red;
border-width: 3px;
border-style: solid
```

or just properly use the shorthand:

```
border: 3px solid red;
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#works {
  border: 3px solid;
  border-color: red;
  }

#broken {
  border-color: red;
  border: 3px solid;
  }
```

```html
<p id="works">Some Text</p>

<p id="broken">doesn't work</p>
```

Place the color after the border

```
border: 3px solid;
border-color: red;
```

While the other answers are better, this worked on my end.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `border-color: red;` and change `border: 3px solid;` to `border: 3px solid red;`

Answer (score 0):

I just want to show you all the cases you can have regarding border color defined in separate classes.

```css
body {
  color: blue;
}
.colorbefore {
  border-color: red;
}
.easybordered {
  border-left: 3px solid;
}
.complexbordered {
  border-left-width: 3px;
  border-left-style: solid;
}
.colorafter {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="easybordered colorbefore">
Blue
</div>

<div class="colorbefore easybordered">
Blue
</div>

<div class="easybordered colorafter">
Red
</div>

<div class="complexbordered colorbefore">
Red
</div>

<div class="complexbordered colorafter">
Red
</div>
```

As already said, what counts is:

- order of the definition of border-style and border-color in the CSS (not the order of the classes given by the "class" attribute")
- border defined as a one-liner or in "pieces" by defining border-style, border-color and border-width
- "color" attribute valid on target div